# How to manually install a node.js module?

Tags: file-upload, node.js, multipart

I want to upload a file to s3 so I want to run the upload program from this article:
http://www.componentix.com/blog/9

For this I need to install the multipart module.
https://github.com/isaacs/multipart-js

But by doing npm install multipart it is giving error

How should I install this multipart module so that I can get this program running?

Comment: what error do you get when you `npm install multipart` ?

Comment: Just download it from github and use as simple nodejs module

Comment: @Emmerman i downloaded but how to use it as simple nodejs module ?

Comment: @neebz it gives 404 error Not found multipart

Comment: Better just add it to npm as git repo.
Usually, you must use `git+ssh` scheme.
`"dependencies": { "project": "git+ssh://user@hostname:project.git#commit-ish" }`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Download lib folder from the https://github.com/isaacs/multipart-js (including all the files inside it).

Put all those files next to your node application in the same folder.

On the top of your application file where you have included other modules like HTTP etc. ..append this >

`var multipart = require("./multipart")`

Comment: How do I add it to `package.json` and `package.lock.json`?

Comment: For me the question is, if I have to add it to package.json and which attributes I choose for such a non-npm folder? Are there any guidelines on this?

Answer (score 38):

You can download the full repo (not just the lib folder) into your application under a folder with the name `node_modules`.

Once you do that, your `require` will just be:

```
var multipart = require('multipart');
```

This is due to the way node resolves module dependencies. It will always look for a `node_modules` directory at the root of your app (and a few other places as well).

It's important you download the full repo and not just the lib folder if you plan to use it this way since the `package.json` file is used to find the main entry point.

```
 { "name" : "multipart"
, "version" : "0.0.0"
, "description" : "A JavaScript library for parsing and writing multipart messages"
, "contributors" :
  [ "Isaac Z. Schlueter <i@izs.me>"
  , "John Wright <mrjjwright@gmail.com>"
  ]
, "repository" :
  { "type" : "git"
  , "url" : "http://github.com/isaacs/multipart-js.git"
  }
, "main" : "lib/multipart"
}
```

The advantage of this is compatibility with using npm install locally in your dev machine.

You can also download the tar file form github. Hit the **Download** button and deploy that with your app. Once that is done in your server you can run

```
npm install <path-to-the-tar-file>
```

That will install `multipart` on the machine for you.

Comment: I haven't had to do this, yet, but this is how I would do it.  It's a better analog to how NPM works than nEEbz's answer, which ends up treating an external dependency like it's part of your application code...

Comment: This is a good solution although the down side of this is the tar file should always be available everywhere its needed but if you are just deploying the compiled file to production it should not be an issue at all especially if you are just using a custom package