# How to install a node.js module without using npm?

Tags: node.js, package, npm

There are quite a few modules which are listed [on node's github page](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules) but are not published with the npm-registry. These modules can't be installed using npm.

What is the correct way to install these nodejs modules after cloning them from Git?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You need to download their source from the github. Find the main file and then include it in your main file.

An example of this can be found here > [How to manually install a node.js module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778474/uploaing-file-in-node-js/5780829#5780829)

Usually you need to find the source and go through the package.json file. There you can find which is the main file. So that you can include that in your application.

To include example.js in your app. Copy it in your application folder and append this on the top of your main js file.

`var moduleName = require("path/to/example.js")`

Comment: Is it possible to import a script from an external URL (like `var myscript = require("http://www.mywebsite.com/myscript.js")`)? It looks like the `require` function doesn't work for external URLs.

Comment: require is actually synchronous, so no, it does not work for external URLs.

Comment: Note: you need to remove the `-master` appended to github libraries; as in change `xxx-master` to `xxx`.

Comment: What do I have to do if there is no `main.js`, because I do server-side rendering? In my case I have a `static` folder without any `main,js`. (My project is set up using Flask Jinja)

Answer (score 75):

> These modules can't be installed using npm.

Actually you can install a module by specifying instead of a name a local path. As long as the repository has a valid `package.json` file it should work.

---

Type `npm -l` and a pretty help will appear like so :

**CLI:**

```
...
install     npm install <tarball file>
                npm install <tarball url>
                npm install <folder>
                npm install <pkg>
                npm install <pkg>@<tag>
                npm install <pkg>@<version>
                npm install <pkg>@<version range>
                
                Can specify one or more: npm install ./foo.tgz bar@stable /some/folder
                If no argument is supplied and ./npm-shrinkwrap.json is 
                present, installs dependencies specified in the shrinkwrap.
                Otherwise, installs dependencies from ./package.json.
```

What caught my eyes was: `npm install <folder>`

In my case I had trouble with `mrt` module so I did this (in a temporary directory)

- Clone the repo

  ```
     git clone https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite.git
  ```
- And I install it globally with:

  ```
     npm install -g ./meteorite
  ```

---

#### Tip:

One can also install in the same manner the repo to a local npm project with:

```
     npm install ../meteorite
```

And also one can create a link to the repo, in case a patch in development is needed:

```
     npm link ../meteorite
```

### Edit:

Nowadays npm supports also github and git repositories (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install), as a shorthand you can run :

```
npm i github.com:some-user/some-repo
```

Comment: most excellent.  I was having trouble with a module as well, so I forked and cloned it down to a sibling directory of my web project, updated all it's dependencies to the latest versions, and then installed it in my web project with 'npm install ../broken_module_name
That worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 but it doesn't work if we don't have network access for npm and the module we are installing with `npm install <folder>` has countless other npm dependencies.

Comment: If npm finds the package into the node_modules, either from the global (not sure here) scope or the local one, it will not attempt to download it again. This means if all the direct dependencies of a repo can be pre-downloaded  and copied to the node_module folder, then it will work.

Answer (score 11):

Download the code from github into the node_modules directory

```
var moduleName = require("<name of directory>")
```

that should do it.

if the module has dependancies and has a package.json, open the module and enter npm install.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think this code works if the main file is named `index.js`

Answer (score 8):

You can clone the module directly in to your local project.

Start terminal. cd in to your project and then:

npm install https://github.com/repo/npm_module.git --save

Comment: The answer I was looking for.

Comment: What happens when the package has been changed, how do you update to the latest version? ATM, the only "solution" I found was to delete the fodler from node_modules, delete the package.json entry and re-add, which is a pain...

Answer (score 1):

Step-by-step:

- let's say you are working on a project `use-gulp` which
  uses(`require`s) `node_modules` like `gulp` and `gulp-util`.
- Now you want to make some modifications to `gulp-util` lib and test it locally with your `use-gulp` project...
- Fork `gulp-util` project on github\bitbucket etc.
- Switch to your project: `cd use-gulp/node_modules`
- Clone `gulp-util` as `gulp-util-dev` : `git clone https://.../gulp-util.git gulp-util-dev`
- Run `npm install` to ensure dependencies of `gulp-util-dev` are available.
- Now you have a mirror of `gulp-util` as `gulp-util-dev`. In your `use-gulp` project, you can now replace: `require('gulp-util')...;` call with : `require('gulp-util-dev')` to test your changes you made to `gulp-util-dev`