# Adding git dependency to nodejs application

Tags: node.js, github, dependencies, requirejs, npm

I'm trying to add [require-cs](https://github.com/jrburke/require-cs) to my nodejs project to I can use r.js with coffeescript files.  I am trying to add it directly to package.json so that I can update it directly with the git repository.  When I add it I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/tmp/npm-1336369606543/1336369606543-0.5654201323632151/package.json'
```

and it doesn't add the git to my application.  My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "mocha": "~1.0.2",
    "chai": "~0.5.3",
    "coffee-script": "~1.3.1",
    "express": "~2.5.9",
    "redis2json": "0.0.5",
    "nohm": "~0.9.0-pre3fixed",
    "redback": "~0.2.8",
    "database-cleaner": "~0.7.0",
    "zombie": "~0.13.4",
    "underscore": "~1.3.3",
    "redis": "~0.7.2",
    "hiredis": "~0.1.14",
    "connect-redis": "~1.3.0",
    "requirejs": "~1.0.8",
    "freebase": "~1.0.1",
    "require-cs": "git://github.com/jrburke/require-cs.git"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to add cs.js to my repository using package.json and npm?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

npm looks for a package.json file in the root of a package. It tells npm how a package is structured, and what to do to install it. The error can't find the `package.json` it's looking for at `git://github.com/jrburke/require-cs.git`.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786433/how-to-install-a-node-js-module-without-using-npm) as well.

http://toolbox.no.de/ is a good npm resource.

Answer (score 0):

Currently require-cs doesn't support npm install. Here is the issue that talked about it:

https://github.com/jrburke/require-cs/issues/12