# 'TypeError: undefined is not a function' error when using 'flickrnode' API

Tags: javascript, node.js, flickr

I'm new to Node.js and I'm trying to get a Flickr API working on my local machine:
https://github.com/ciaranj/flickrnode
I have installed the flickr module with npm install flickr.

The simplest call is:

```
var FlickrAPI= require('flickr').FlickrAPI;
var sys= require('sys');
var flickr= new FlickrAPI(your_api_key_here);

// Search for photos with a tag of 'badgers'
flickr.photos.search({tags:'badgers'},  function(error, results) {
    sys.puts(sys.inspect(results));
});
```

I've changed 'sys' to 'util' as node prompted me to and added my api key so I'm calling:

```
var FlickrAPI= require('flickr').FlickrAPI;
var sys= require('util');
var flickr= new FlickrAPI('...');

// Search for photos with a tag of 'badgers'
flickr.photos.search({tags:'badgers'},  function(error, results) {
    sys.puts(sys.inspect(results));
});
```

Running node myfile.js, I get:

```
var flickr= new FlickrAPI('a513719086ba8c3a28d2c7726939b58e');
            ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/charm/ciaranj-flickrnode-8a9d85f/lib/simple.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

Does anyone know how I overcome this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that `npm install flickr` installs https://github.com/sujal/node-flickr, not the one you're looking for, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786433/ explains how to install node packages manually

Comment: Yes you're right and that one is much newer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install flickr` installs https://github.com/sujal/node-flickr, not the one you're looking for. [How to install a node.js module without using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786433) explains how to install node packages manually