# Cannot load module I put manually in /node_modules/ directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-webkit, google-speech-api

I want to use a module I put in /node_modules/ manually, I simply copy/pasted the files and installed dependencies with npm, I'm using NWJS 0.16.0.

When I type `var speech = require('speech')` in my app.js (or anywhere else), I get the following error - `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'speech'`.

I tried doing `var speech = require('/node_modules/speech')`, `var speech = require('./node_modules/speech')` and even full path `C:\\...\\project\\node_modules\\speech` with the same result.

If someone has an idea of what I might be doing wrong, I'd appreciate the input.

`npm install -g ./speech` yields no results

Note: this is the Google Cloud Speech API

Comment: do you have it in your package.json? how is it named in there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a node.js module without using npm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786433/how-to-install-a-node-js-module-without-using-npm)

Comment: I did not have it in package.json, I tried adding with no effect. Also installing it globally with `npm install -g ./speech` did not work

Comment: Check `ls node_modules/speech`. If that is there, the `speech` directory` is probably missing an` index.js` or equivalent.

Comment: There is not index.js, but there is a package.json in the /speech directory - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/speech

Comment: try npm install speech --save or npm install -g speech

Answer (score 0):

try `**npm install speech --save**` or `**npm install -g speech**`