# How to locally install ngeo framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openlayers-3

How to locally install ngeo http://www.camptocamp.com/en/actualite/ngeo-library-combining-angularjs-openlayers-3/ (not by npm) to use it for javascript development? Am new to ngeo

Comment: it appears to be in bower, so you should be able to `bower install ngeo`, if your familiar with that technology

Comment: you need not know the framework to install it. These frameworks are registered as node modules so that you could easily install in your system if node is installed in your system. I f you really dont want to use node, reffer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786433/how-to-install-a-node-js-module-without-using-npm