# How to use Reactjs Datepicker when not using Webpack/Node?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, babeljs

I am trying to build a reactjs page inside a VisaulForce Page(Salesforce) which means I can't easily setup webpack and all those great tools.

I been using babel-standalone which has helped alot but now I ran into the problem with trying to get a datepicker to work.

I have these scripts

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react-dom.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.min.js"> </script
```

Then all my code is in between

```
 <script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2017,react,stage-0" data-plugins="transform-decorators-legacy"> </script>
```

I tried to use [this datepicker plugin](https://hacker0x01.github.io/react-datepicker/) but I get the following errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactOnclickoutside2.default) is not a function
    at Object.module.exports (react-datepicker.js:1003)
    at __webpack_require__ (react-datepicker.js:30)
    at Object.module.exports (react-datepicker.js:573)
    at __webpack_require__ (react-datepicker.js:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (react-datepicker.js:65)
    at __webpack_require__ (react-datepicker.js:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (react-datepicker.js:50)
    at react-datepicker.js:53
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (react-datepicker.js:9)
    at react-datepicker.js:10
```

and

```
Datepicker is undefined.
```

Comment: maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786433/how-to-install-a-node-js-module-without-using-npm alternatively, why not just use the native input date?

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question looks ok, but you have not shown how you are referencing the DatePicker plugin from react-datepicker;
It is NOT enough to reference

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-datepicker/2.8.0/react-datepicker.js"></script>
```

You must also reference the dependencies of this library; classnames, date-fns, prop-types, react-onclickoutside, react-popper

Then write a console.log(window) to check if the window.DatePicker object has loaded properly, and you can continue from there.