# Manually install modules for Angular 5 without npm

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular5, npm-install

I wish to manually install npm modules for my Angular project.  I am behind a proxy and instead of setting the proxy information for my npm config file, I just wish to manually download npm modules and add them to my npm-cache/node_modules folders.

I have seen this old post but haven't found anything more recent: [How to install a node.js module without using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786433/how-to-install-a-node-js-module-without-using-npm)

One of the modules I want to install is ng2-signalr. I went to GitHub, downloaded the source for the package, and added it to my node_modules folder.

After doing this I can import the module without error:

```
import { SignalRConfiguration } from 'ng2-signalr';
```

When I add code that uses the class:

```
const c = new SignalRConfiguration();
```

I get the following error:

> `index.ts` is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the `'files'` or `'include'` property.

Am I missing a step for manually installing a node module? Should I download to my npm cache folder?

I'm aware that I have to pay mind to dependencies of these manually installed modules. Also I know that the cache folder gets overwritten when you need to reinstall and that the node_modules folder is not usually included when you check in your source due to the size, but I only wish to experiment with the library.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Add the directory or index file you wish to use in your Typescript config. Example in `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
"include": [
    "../path/to/library"
]
```

Rebuild after this. This is likely due to the 3rd party not setting up the `package.json` correctly.

Comment: This helped me eliminate the build errors, but I haven't been able to get the signalr module to work. Some problem with "negotiating the connection."