# How do I add a library to react-native project manually?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, npm

There is a library react-native-iron-source on GitHub. But this library is not in the npm.

How can I add the library to my react-native project manually? So that it works correctly with js code, iOS and Android?

Comment: are you sure that [react-native-iron-source](https://github.com/squaretwo/react-native-iron-source) is not in `NPM`?

Comment: read [readme](https://github.com/squaretwo/react-native-iron-source#getting-started) file correctly

Comment: @flix Yes: "npm ERR! 404 Not Found: react-native-iron-source@latest"

Comment: give me a full link of the library that you mention above, ill try to install it on my project, _Also try to `npm install react-native-iron-source --save` without `@latest`_

Comment: @ShahzadMirza Readme doesn't work correctly

Comment: @flix https://github.com/squaretwo/react-native-iron-source

Comment: yeah [read this issues](https://github.com/squaretwo/react-native-iron-source/issues/2#issuecomment-291286185) to the repo author doesn't even find time to add explanation that why its no available on npm.

Comment: @ShahzadMirza yes, I read the issue. But, the issue is one year. I would like know how to add the library manually without npm repository

Comment: this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786433/how-to-install-a-node-js-module-without-using-npm) will be helpful for adding the package

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk putting repo as your dependency as mentioned in Answer and start npm again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
         ...
        "react-native-iron-source": "git://github.com/bsy/react-native-iron-source.git"
    },
```