# Install React Dependencies using NPM on a github repo

Tags: reactjs, github, gatsby

I want to install this plugin : https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/?=SEO

On my project located in this repo : https://github.com/krityk/krityk.github.io

( This project is hosted on netlify )

I dont know how to use npm command on github.

Comment: What do you mean by "use npm command on github"? You install dependencies locally.

Comment: add dependency with report link like this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650202/how-do-i-add-a-library-to-react-native-project-manually/49650579#49650579

Comment: Thanx for the help , the problem is when I install the dependencies locally it add 44981 changed files, so I cant commit to the branch. here is a screen : screenshot.net/fr/w800ls9. And for the report link I didnt find this plugin on github

Answer (score 0):

How did you create that project?
Usually you will install dependencies locally in your project with `npm install --save gatsby-plugin-react-helmet react-helmet`?

After making your changes, you would push your changes to GitHub, there Netlify will build it and deploy it automatically (this depends in your setup).

Comment: Thanx for the help , the problem is when I install the dependencies locally it add 44981 changed files, so I cant commit to the branch.   here is a screen : https://screenshot.net/fr/w800ls9

Comment: Oh, that is completely different, you need to create a `.gitignore` file in the root of your project, then add `node_modules/` to it, like this: https://www.gitignore.io/api/node