# copy aws-sdk manually to nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have downloaded aws-sdk from AWS and copied the folder to nodejs installed directory at below Path:

```
c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\aws-sdk
```

we have network restriction at server level to install aws-sdk using command prompt so we cannot use  `>npm install aws-sdk`

When I am trying to execute sample code, I am getting an error stating: `cannot find module ;aws-sdk'`

Please can anyone help? if any configuration is missing or missed when we manually copy 'aws-sdk' library files to nodejs folder.

Note: I am trying this on Windows OS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a node.js module without using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786433/how-to-install-a-node-js-module-without-using-npm)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add aws-sdk to the "dependencies" section in your **package.json** file. Like the following:

```
"dependencies": {
  "aws-sdk": "^2.418.0"
}
```