# Where to download npm modules manually?

Tags: npm, npm-install

Where can I manually download npm modules? Due to requirements I don't want to use npm on the command line.

Comment: Usually each npm package has a link to their github repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a node.js module without using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786433/how-to-install-a-node-js-module-without-using-npm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to install a node.js module without using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786433/how-to-install-a-node-js-module-without-using-npm) Looks like your question is also here. You need to download their source from the github. Find the main file and then include it in your main file.