# npm install -g cordova windows 8 error

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I'm trying to install cordova, in windows 8, but throws me this error.
I'm running the cmd as administrator and the file "C: \ Program Files (x86) \ nodejs \ node.exe" I configured to be executed as administrator.

```
    19 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 17:24:08
    20 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
    21 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect EACCES
    22 info trying registry request attempt 2 at 17:24:19
    23 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
    24 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect EACCES
    25 info trying registry request attempt 3 at 17:25:20
    26 http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
    27 silly lockFile de8d9fad-cordova cordova@
    28 silly lockFile de8d9fad-cordova cordova@
    29 error Error: connect EACCES
    29 error     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    29 error     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
    29 error  { [Error: connect EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'connect' }
    30 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
    31 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
    32 error command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
    33 error cwd C:\
    34 error node -v v0.10.22
    35 error npm -v 1.3.14
    36 error syscall connect
    37 error code EACCES
    38 error errno EACCES
    39 error stack Error: connect EACCES
    39 error stack     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    39 error stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
    40 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manually install a node.js module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778474/how-to-manually-install-a-node-js-module)