# Can't install node module 'graphene-pk11'

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install graphene-pk11 node js module to interact with SoftHSM2. I'm using **node v4.6.0 and npm 2.15.9**

If I execute the command npm `install graphene-pk11`, I get the error `enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/home/lzuniga/development/HsmTest/node_modules/graphene-pk11/build/console/console.js'`, which I looked up on multiple forums and tried a lot of solutions/workarounds like running `npm cache clean` or removing the `node_modules` folder.

I also downloaded the graphene source from [github's repo](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/graphene) and tried to use it as stated in neebz and theprogrammer's answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778474/how-to-manually-install-a-node-js-module/5780829#5780829) (created a `node_modules` folder in my project folder and put graphene source folder there, then on my app.js file I added `var graphene = require("graphene-pk11");`), but the error was `Cannot find module 'graphene-pk11'`

It should be an npm issue, but I don't know if there could be a different problem in this module, since none of the solutions for the enoent error worked for me...

**EDIT**
If I run `npm install` inside the graphene project directory that I downloaded and copied into the node_modules directory, I get the following output:

```
$ npm install
npm WARN package.json graphene-pk11@2.0.11 No bin file found at ./build/console/console.js
npm WARN deprecated watch@0.19.3: Install watch@1.0.0 instead

> pkcs11js@1.0.3 install /home/lzuniga/development/HsmTest/node_modules/graphene/node_modules/pkcs11js
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/lzuniga/development/HsmTest/node_modules/graphene/node_modules/pkcs11js/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/main.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/dl.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/const.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/error.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/v8_convert.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/template.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/mech.o
../src/pkcs11/mech.cpp: In member function ‘void Mechanism::Free()’:
../src/pkcs11/mech.cpp:121:15: warning: deleting ‘void*’ is undefined [enabled by default]
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/param.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/param_aes.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/param_rsa.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/param_ecdh.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/pkcs11/pkcs11.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/async.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/node.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11.node
  COPY Release/pkcs11.node
make: Leaving directory `/home/lzuniga/development/HsmTest/node_modules/graphene/node_modules/pkcs11js/build'
npm WARN engine http-auth@2.4.10: wanted: {"node":">=5"} (current: {"node":"4.6.0","npm":"2.15.9"})
npm WARN engine apache-crypt@1.1.2: wanted: {"node":">=5"} (current: {"node":"4.6.0","npm":"2.15.9"})
npm WARN engine apache-md5@1.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=5"} (current: {"node":"4.6.0","npm":"2.15.9"})
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! path /home/lzuniga/development/HsmTest/node_modules/graphene/build/console/console.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/home/lzuniga/development/HsmTest/node_modules/graphene/build/console/console.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/lzuniga/development/HsmTest/node_modules/graphene/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Is the error message literally showing `/path-to-project/node_modules/graphene-pk11/build/console/console.js`? Because unless you have a folder called `path-to-project` in your root of course it's going to fail. Perhaps you should show the real commands you're using.

Comment: No, I changed it for the actual path, to avoid more confusions

Comment: Author of this library, just saw this. Are you still having issues? If so please file a bug in the repo, happy to help out in any way.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with their publish to npm. The problem is that at the time of running `npm install graphene-pk11`, the following file that it's package.json is looking for doesn't exist.

```
  "bin": {
    "graphene": "./build/console/console.js"
  },
```

I tried installing it into a fresh directory myself and had the same problem.

You can use it if you clone the source code. After cloning, navigate to the project directory, which should be called `graphene`. Run npm install inside the graphene project. There's a line inside their `package.json` that says `"postinstall": "npm run build",` which automatically runs the build process after installing all necessary dependencies.

Assuming you cloned the source code into your node_modules, you can access the module as follows:

```
var graphene = require('graphene');
```

The issue you had in trying to use the source code was that you hadn't run `npm install` and you were trying to require `graphene-pk11` rather than `graphene`.

We're requiring `graphene` here because the name of the directory inside node_modules is `graphene`, or at least that's the name of the directory when I cloned the source. You could always rename the project directory in `node_modules` to `graphene-pk11`, and then you would just require `graphene-pk11`. I tried this out on my computer and all of this worked. Let me know if you have any issues.

This would be a temporary fix though. It shouldn't be necessary to do this in order to use their code. I would open an issue on github with them if I were you. Their `package.json` also says `"prepublish": "npm run build",` which should also run the build process before publishing to npm, but for whatever reason, that didn't work out.

Comment: Yes, the project directory is called graphene, I ran `npm install` in that directory but I got the same problem, the console.js file doesn't exist. This is part of the output:

`npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"

npm ERR! node v4.6.0

npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9

npm ERR! path /home/lzuniga/development/HsmTest/node_modules/graphene/build/console/console.js

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/home/lzuniga/development/HsmTest/node_modules/graphene/build/console/console.js'`

Comment: I had already tried renaming the project directory "graphene-pk11" so that it would match the name property in package.json